# Unity ball with constant speed

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making 2D mobile game and I have a ball, but my ball doesn't have a constant moving speed. What I need to do?
When I build game on my android device, ball have a various speed. In that case, my game is not playable.

I hope that someone can help me. Thanks.

This is on my start function:

```
void Start () {
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ()
        .AddForce (new Vector2 (1f, 0.5f)* Time.deltaTime * force);
}
```

Is it a good practice if I used in code " Application.LoadLevel ("__Scena_0"); " to load existing scene when I lose " life" ? Problem happens when I lost " life " and try playing game in second chance.

My update function is about OnTriggerEnter2D when my ball hit trigger objects.

EDIT 23.12.2015. : problem solve with adding physics material (fiction 0) and adding to script:

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
...
SceneManager.LoadScene ("MainScene");
```

Comment: Do you have some code to show?
Is your problem that you don't know how to implement that, or is something not working properly?

Comment: This is on my start function:

void Start () 
 { 

  GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (new Vector2 (1f, 0.5f)* Time.deltaTime * force);
}

I added bounciness to my walls and ball

Comment: But what do you mean with "have various speed" and "my game is not playable"? Please explain what are you expecting and what are you seeing.
Are you expecting the ball to move at a constant speed, but it's not?

Comment: No, when I build that game on my android device, first time: ball moving ok(like on my unity editor), second time(after lost " life "): ball moving with very very high speed. I have walls, and sometimes, my ball go cross the wall. :(

Comment: So please, update your question with a better description and show more code including when you re-create the ball, the update function, and other things that might help understand it. If not, it's only possible to guess.

Comment: You've commented on a couple answers now saying that your problem has been solved, so please be sure to accept an answer if that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the calculation of the force vector:

```
new Vector2 (1f, 0.5f) * Time.deltaTime * force
```

You are using Time.deltaTime as a factor, which means that the applied force is not constant, but depending on the deltaTime, which is the duration of the last frame. This explains why it changes randomly.

I don't think Time.deltaTime is what you want here, try just removing the factor and adjusting the "force" factor accordingly. You should now have a constant force applied, independent from the platform you play on.

Comment: Its ok bro, but now, my ball loosing speed. Speed is not constant now.
I want a ball which have the same speed, always. If this is a possible.

Comment: If speed is decreasing, this is because of friction. You can create a new Physics Material and set its friction to 0. You then assign this material to your Colliders. You should no longer lose speed to friction.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new [Physics Material](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html), set friction zero and add it to your object. If your object has no friction, its speed cannot be decreased. Then, use `AddForce()` on Rigidbody2D to speed up.

Comment: I used this before, and I have the same problem. Is it a good practice if I used in code " Application.LoadLevel ("__Scena_0"); " to load existing scene when I lose " life" ? Problem happens when I lost " life " and try playing game in second chance.

Comment: use "Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);" to reset current level

Comment: Thanks for that. You solve my problem. But my problem now is that my ball loosing speed :D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your ball and colliding walls have bouncy materials with no friction. Try

```
public float _ballSpeed = 2.5f;
Rigidbody2D _rb;

void Start()
{
    _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    _rb.velocity = Vector2.one * _ballSpeed;
}
void Update()
{

}
```

From this you can control ball speed through `_ballSpeed`

```
//========== OR ==========//
```

If you want to retain speed even after ball destruction.

Retain _ballSpeed in any global static variable.

Suppose you have a class named `Globals`, declare a variable like,

```
public class Globals
{
    public static float BALL_SPEED = 2.5f;
}
```

Now in Ball Script

```
Rigidbody2D _rb;

void Start()
{
    _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    _rb.velocity = Vector2.one * Globals.BALL_SPEED;
}
void Update()
{

}
```

Comment: after your code, my ball don't have bounces from the walls, ball is on the right corner and constantly hitting the wall

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't need to have this. It's about physics material with fiction 0 and removing Time.deltatime. 
Thank you very much :)